# Запятая после "по крайней мере"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в этих скобках: В связи с высокой стоимостью трубопроводная арматура из хастеллоев получила (по крайней мере в РФ) очень широкое распространение в первую очередь на опытных и опытно-промышленных установках, связанных с обращением вышеупомянутых сред.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: по крайней мере в РФ (оценочное выражение относится к конкретному слову).

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

Мы довольно часто употребляем слова "по крайней мере", "во всяком случае" и при этом обычно не очень задумываемся над их смыслом. А что же всё-таки означают эти "крайние меры" и как они соотносятся со "всякими случаями"?

Когда мы что-то утверждаем, то часто возникает вопрос о тех границах, в которых наше утверждение верно. Вот, к примеру, предложение: "По крайне мере, я понимаю это так". Автор может предполагать, что его мнение разделяют другие люди, но точно он может это сказать только о себе. Таким образом, слова "по крайней мере" и "во всяком случае" гарантируют верность информации.

Эти оценочные выражения в необособленном виде считаются частицами, а в обособленном - вводными словами. Если они относятся к конкретным словам, то не обособляются как частицы. Если же оценка делается для всего сообщения, то это вводное слово. Исходя из  этого и строится предложение с определенной структурой.

ПРИМЕРЫ

Так, по крайней мере, казалось ему (общая оценка сообщения).

Я по крайней мере такой доброте никакой цены не придаю (оценочное выражение относится к местоимению "я").

Answer (score 1):

Здесь "по крайней мере" не вводное словосочетание, а частица. Запятая не нужна.

http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_556

Answer (score 0):

Не нужна. См. пункт 5 из параграфа 99.

Comment: Нужна. См. п. 6)))